# Game is lagging when drawing buffered image

Tags: java, memory, game-development

I am making a game and I want to add the option to fullscreen so it scales all graphics to the new expanded JFrame. Code works great and does exactly what I want, but now I have a problem and I'm assuming it's a memory problem or something because what I am doing is drawing everything to a buffered image and then drawing the buffered image scaled to the JFrame's size. Before, when I just drew everything directly to the frame, I would get ~900 frames constant. But when I implement my new method it drops right away to 120 frames and freezes for about half a second every few seconds.

This is the current method:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    
    BufferedImage screen = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) screen.getGraphics();
    
    g2d.translate(-Camera.getX(), -Camera.getY());
    
    level.render(g2d);
    handler.render(g2d);
    
    g2d.translate(Camera.getX(), Camera.getY());
    
    g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, fullWidth, fullHeight, null);
    
    bs.show();
    g2d.dispose();
    g.dispose();
}
```

And this is what the method looked like before that was giving 900 or more frames with no freezing:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    g2d.translate(-Camera.getX(), -Camera.getY());
    
    level.render(g);
    handler.render(g);
    
    g2d.translate(Camera.getX(), Camera.getY());
    
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get e.g. the height of the image and make that the loop counter stop quantity, then paint a line at a time in a method. The JVM "stack" is supposedly max assigned on the startup command line flags total 1 megabyte for -Xss. You also should reserve around 1gb space for an image in the heap eden e.t.c.  https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes see also garbage collector docs

"dispose" on graphics only nulls the reference.

```
System.gc();
```

This will call the garbage collector to clean up the RAM.
With imaging programs invariably they require reserving some RAM for the JVM on the startup command line. Too it is possible to pass flags to the JVM on how to handle garbage, usually System.gc is fine but with heavy server usage they require garbage collector schemes put in as flags. See G1 garbage collector if you need a scheme (900 frames - seems you definitely require a garbage collection scheme too).
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html

The "show" method of a top level window such as Frame or Window is to initialize onto the screen once only  NOT for the image painting itself, images you need to  repaint its matrix (Raster) of the image by getting a Graphics object from a method of the exact e.g. Buffered image you want to paint and do not need to dispose of it for the next image pixel setting (it belongs to that image) but may need to put it somewhere permanent such as global reference so it is not destroyed when a method finishes,  and then call the Window,Frame,panel "repaint" method after setting all the pixel values.
With java.swing J system you do not use "show" , you feed a boolean true to method "setVisible" , It also requires to wrap setVisible in SwingUtilities.invokeLater , nothing too difficult to google.
If anything solves it well download the Sun Microsystems Java tutorials (now Oracle) URL example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html
get yourself a copy after sign up its free to devs.

Comment: Hey, so I implemented what you said but it didn't change anything I am still getting ~90 fps now. This is my command line `-Xmx1G -Xss1g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200` And I replaced the graphics dispose methods with System.gc(); Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You remain in requirement of the Graph.dispose , but i think i see what is wrong! the .show() method is only to show the Window or JWindow (should be the latter as the old one is almost legacy and the J version swing extends from it) I.show() is only for STARTING THE WINDOW SAID ONCE ONLY. Everything after is the aka "canvas window use to paint on" call .repaint() after each setting an image! nb try to call the System.gc() only after at least 10 repaints anyhow, it is only a request to the garbage collector. Again with image programs its sensible to at least have a command line RAM flags.

Comment: Merchant this does not work, if you do not run the show() for the buffer strategy then the frame remains blank. I tried everything you suggested and none of it made any difference I still get like 60 fps. If you do not include show() after every render frame then you get a blank screen.

Comment: Thought bs.show()  was amiss,  Read "Here is an example of how buffer strategies can be created and used"  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html  The setVisible(true) would be good to see the paint system buffer.show is simply getting next cache to paint.

Comment: conentsLost() and contentsRestored() appear integrally required in it too. What canvas or frame component are you using. NB repaint() could be required in it.

Comment: Are you using a resize algorithm to resize each frame, should also have a constant Field value java.awt.Image has a resizing algorithm but requires individually lifting each pixel out into either a Raster or buffered image.

Comment: I am just using a java.awt.Canvas component on a JFrame. I am making a basic 2D game should I just use lwjgl or is that overkill?

Comment: java.awt.Component is what to take a look at, both JFrame and Canvas extend from a Component. 900fps is immense 60fps is like a sports video anyhow. For images you must use GC requests to clean RAM, every 5th image load if it is large  You must call repaint() on a "Component" after a visual change sent to it. JFrame should be set setIgnoreRepaint(false)

Comment: You should also be using the Canvas Component method createImage() as the preferred way to associate image and buffer it's a java.awt.Image and that has a resize method in its class.

Comment: and presuming "BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy" "this" means Canvas.

Comment: Finally found the Component java awt.Image part of Component , Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() and Component also has prepareImage() and imageUpdate() for buffer strategy "binding".